# When creating a feathers service with nedb, is it possible to define a unique index?

Tags: unique-constraint, feathersjs, nedb, feathers-service

I made a feathers service using nedb with `feathers generate service`
Let's say the service is called `warehouses` and I want to have a unique index on the name.
The Nedb docs tell me I can create a unique index with `db.ensureIndex`, but I cannot seem to find WHERE in my feathers code I should do this.
Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, so I think I just found it :-) 
I'll leave it here if anyone else encounters this.

Just open the model file under `/src/models/<servicename>.model.js`.

And then adjust like so:

```
const NeDB = require('nedb');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function (app) {
  const dbPath = app.get('nedb');
  const Model = new NeDB({
    filename: path.join(dbPath, 'warehouses.db'),
    autoload: true
  });

  // here it is: create a unique index on the name
  Model.ensureIndex({ fieldName: 'name', unique: true })

  return Model;
};
```